# Como remover um struct armazenado em arquivo em c?

Tags: c, arquivo, struct

Acho que não expliquei bem no título

Tenho um código de agenda onde consigo Adicionar contato, editar, listar e fica armazenado em um arquivo agenda.txt

só que estou com dificuldades de remover um contato que foi previamente adicionado

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


struct usuario{
    int num;    
    char nome[50];  
    char telefone[20];
    char email[20]; 
    char endere[20];
};

FILE *arquivo;

struct usuario C;

// Função que exibe o menu de opções
char menu(){

    system("cls");
    printf("\n- - - - - - - - AGENDA DE CONTATOS - - - - - - - -\n\n");

    printf("Opcoes:\n");
    printf("1 - Cadastrar contato.\n");
    printf("2 - Listar contatos cadastrados.\n");
    printf("3 - Procurar contato. \n");
    printf("4 - Editar contato.\n");
    printf("5 - Excluir contato.\n");
    printf("6 - Sair.\n\n");
    printf("Digite a opcao:");

    return (getche());
}

// Função de pesquisa pelo número de inscrição
int BuscaInsc(int n){
    fread(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);

    while(!feof(arquivo)){      
        if(C.num == n){     
            fseek(arquivo,sizeof(C),SEEK_CUR);      
            return 1;       
        }       
    fread(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);  
    }   
    return 0;
}

// Função de cadastro de usuário
void cadastrarUsuario(){    
    int i;  
    arquivo = fopen("agenda.txt","a+b");

    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n\n\nDigite o codigo de inscricao: "); 
    scanf("%d",&C.num);

    if(C.num != 0){ 
        printf("\nDigite o nome: ");    
        fflush(stdin);  
        gets(C.nome);   
        printf("\nDigite o telefone: ");    
        fflush(stdin);  
        gets(C.telefone);
        printf("\nDigite o e-mail: ");  
        fflush(stdin);  
        gets(C.email);  
        printf("\nDigite o endereco: ");    
        fflush(stdin);  
        gets(C.endere); 
        fwrite(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo); 
        getchar();
    }

    else{
        printf("\nCodigo de inscricao ja cadastrado.\n");   
    }
    fclose(arquivo);

}

// Função que lista usuários cadastrados
void listarUsuario(){   
    int i=0;    
    arquivo = fopen("cliente.txt","rw");

    if(arquivo == NULL){    
        printf("\nErro ao abrir arquivo\n");    
        return; 
    }

    fread(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);  
    printf("\n\n\nCadastros:\n\n\n");

    while(!feof(arquivo)){  
        i++;    
        printf("\n- - - - - - - - AGENDA - - - - - - - -"); 
        printf("\n____________________________________\n\n");   
        printf("Codigo de inscricao: %d\n Nome: %s\n Telefone: %s\n E-mail: %s\n Endereco: %s\n"    
        ,C.num,C.nome,C.telefone,C.email,C.endere);     
        printf("\n____________________________________\n\n");

        fread(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);  

        if(feof(arquivo) || (i == 20)){
            break;  
            getchar();  
            getchar();  
        }
    }
    fclose(arquivo);

}

// Função que busca usuário pelo código
void buscarUsuario(){
    int insc;
    arquivo = fopen("agenda.txt","rw");

    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("\nErro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n Digite o codigo de inscricao: ");
    scanf("%d",&insc);

    if(BuscaInsc(insc) == 0)
        printf("\nCodigo de Inscricao invalido!\n");
    else {
        fread(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);
        printf("\n- - - - - - - - AGENDA - - - - - - - -\n");
        printf("\n____________________________________\n\n");
        printf("\nInscricao: %d\n",C.num);
        printf("Nome: %s\n",C.nome);
        printf("Telefone: %s\n",C.telefone);
        printf("E-mail: %s\n",C.email);
        printf("Endereco:%s\n",C.endere);
        printf("\n____________________________________\n\n");

        getchar();
        getchar();
    }

    fclose(arquivo);

}

// Função de edição de usuário
void editarUsuario()
{
    int insc;
    arquivo = fopen("agenda.txt","rw");
    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("\nErro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n Digite o codigo de inscricao: ");
    scanf("%d",&insc);

    //BuscaInsc(insc);

    if(BuscaInsc(insc) == 0)
        printf("\nCodigo de inscricao invalido!\n");
    else
        arquivo = fopen("agenda.txt","wb");

    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("\n\nInscricao: ");
    scanf("%d",&C.num);

    if(C.num !=0){
        printf("\nNome: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(C.nome);
        printf("\nDigite o telefone: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(C.telefone);
        printf("\nDigite o e-mail: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(C.email);
        printf("\nDigite o endereco: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(C.endere);
        printf("\nAlteracao realizada com sucesso!");
        fwrite(&C,sizeof(C),1,arquivo);
        getchar();
    }

    else
        printf("\nCodigo de inscricao ja cadastrado.\n");
    fclose(arquivo);

}


// Função de edição de usuário
void apagarUsuario()
{



}


// Função principal
main(){
    char op;
    while(op!='6'){
        op = menu();
        switch(op){
            case '1':cadastrarUsuario();
            break;

            case '2':listarUsuario();
            break;

            case '3':buscarUsuario();
            break;

            case '4':editarUsuario();
            break;

            case '5':apagarUsuario();
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        system("pause");
    }

}
```

Comment: Amigo, não sou especialista em Structs, mas struct usuario c, é só um único usuário, creio que você não consegue inserir vários valores, ou seja, somente uma pessoa, se quiser outros acho que deveria ter outros usuários, ou senão usar uma lista encadeada.. perdão se falei asneira..

Comment: não existe isso. `struct` determina uma área na memória. Se tem um arquivo com uma sequência delas o que pode fazer é ler o arquivo de entrada e ir gravando igual num arquivo na saída. Ao encontrar a que quer apagar não copia. E copia até o final. Apaga o arquvo original. Muda o nome do novo para o nome do original. Simples assim.

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa forma de fazer isso, seria criar um novo arquivo. Copiar todos os contactos para o novo arquivo, na excepção daquele que se quer apagar. E no fim, remover o velho arquivo e renomear o novo.

```
void apagarUsuario()
{
    FILE* arquivo = fopen("agenda.txt", "rw");
    FILE* novoArquivo = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    char nome[50];

    printf("Digite o nome do usuário a ser excluido: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);

    while(!feof(arquivo)){
        fread(&C, sizeof(C), 1, arquivo);
        if(strcmp(nome, C.nome)){
            fwrite(&C, sizeof(C), 1, novoArquivo);
        }
    }
    fclose(novoArquivo);
    fclose(arquivo);
    remove("agenda.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "agenda.txt");
}
```

Comment: muito agradecido pela força, colega

Comment: Além dessa possibilidade você pode incluir em sua estrutura um campo informando se aquele registro está válido ou deve ser considerado excluído (exclusão lógica). Neste caso você deve modificar sua rotina de inclusão pesquisando primeiro se existe alguma exclusão lógica e, caso exista, ocupar o espaço disponibilizado.